# 親文字とルビの間隔を個別に調整する方法はありますか？

Tags: latex

大文字にアクセント記号がつくとアセンダラインを超えてしまい、ルビに被ります。`\rubyintergap` での調整はすべてのルビに効いてしまい、通常の親文字はルビと間隔が空きすぎて間延びしてしまいます。個別に親文字とルビの間隔を調整する方法はありますでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

pxrubricaでいうところのグループ毎にrubyintergapを指定すればできなくはなさそうです。
ただ、記述が面倒なのとバランスが悪いのが難です。

##### rubyintergapの効果

[image: rubyintergapの例]

##### ソース

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{jsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{pxrubrica}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item \textbackslash rubyintergapなし\\
\ruby[g]{PR\^{O}BL\`{E}M\^{A}T\"{I}CRUBY}{かぶってしまうやっかいな} \ruby[g]{RUBY}{ルビ} 

\item \textbackslash rubyintergap\{0.24\}\\
\rubyintergap{0.24}
\ruby[g]{PR\^{O}BL\`{E}M\^{A}T\"{I}CRUBY}{かぶってしまうやっかいな} \ruby[g]{RUBY}{ルビ}
\rubyintergap{0.0}

\item グループ毎に\textbackslash rubyintergap\{0.24\}\\
\ruby[g]{PR}{かぶ}
\rubyintergap{0.24}\ruby[g]{\^{O}}{っ}
\rubyintergap{0.0}\ruby[g]{BL}{てし}
\rubyintergap{0.24}\ruby[g]{\`{E}}{ま}
\rubyintergap{0.0}\ruby[g]{M}{う}
\rubyintergap{0.24}\ruby[g]{\^{A}}{や}
\rubyintergap{0.24}\ruby[g]{T\"{I}}{っか}
\rubyintergap{0.0}\ruby[g]{CRUBY}{いな}
\rubyintergap{0.0}\ruby[g]{ RUBY}{ルビ}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```